# URL request from Python

Tags: python, http, get

I have a Server running and its always listening to the `value` field 
I can make a requests from a web browser from the URL,

```
Eg: http://192.168.1.101/value=1
```

How can i make a request like this from Python, i tried the above code but it doesnt seem to work.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = 'http://192.168.1.101/value=1'
request = Request(url)
```

My server is listening in the above formate.(GET)

```
GET /value=1 HTTP/1.1
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use requests module

```
import requests as req
url = 'http://192.168.1.101/value=1'
resp = req.get(url)
print(resp.text) # Printing response
```

Comment: I get an error, raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

Comment: just try any other url instaead of local one. 
say,  url = "https://www.google.co.in/"

Comment: It Works now! Silly mistake :P